# call a mongo collection using a variable

Tags: python, mongodb

I have generic collection name in my mongodb and I want to use a string variable to call these collection. For example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client= MongoClient()
db = client.mydb
collec_id='123'

mycollection = db.collection123
```

How can I get `mycollection`using `collec_id`

Any help appreciated

Comment: `mycollection = db['collection' + collec_id]`

Comment: @user3100115: This fully answers the question, so you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach posted accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seems noticed you cannot use dot (`.`) here. You need to use bracket `[]` to compute your collections' name. Here you use the `+` operator to concatenate `collection` and `collect_id`.

```
mycollection = db['collection' + collec_id]
```