# Putting mongodb collection name as a variable doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

Beginner coder here, so sorry if this question is a simple one, but I have been trying for a while to get this to work.

I'm trying to put a collection name as a variable but the code is resulting in a KeyError on [key] and I'm not sure why. When I replace 'collection' with 'X' in the 'cursor' line, it works. Any help please?

```
collection = 'X'
cursor = db.collection.find()
values = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))[key]
print(values)
```

Comment: Studio 3T for MongoDB allows you to use `db.getCollection("collectionName")` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/).  You should check if panda(?) has something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have already run db.collection_names() and 'X' (in my example) exists.

Comment: Ok?  My comment wasn't saying to verify that the collection exists.  I'm confused.

Comment: I guess my question is: why should changing: ```db.X.find()``` to ```collection = 'X'``` ```cursor = db.collection.find()``` cause this to fail.

Comment: because `collection` in the expression `db.collection` is taken as a literal, not a variable.  `db.collection.find` is the same as `db.getCollection('collection').find` Edit: that's at least how it works in Studio 3T, in the mongo shell, and javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [call a mongo collection using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270315/call-a-mongo-collection-using-a-variable)

Comment: I tried the following and it seemed to work: ```cursor = db['%s' % collection].find()```